# Zend Framework index in the url

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm writing a Zend Framework application and its not a big deal but I can't figure out (even after googling) how to remove the /index/ from the url

So I currently have this

http://myapplication.local/index/home

When I really want

http://myapplication.local/home

I understand it **may** be possible to do this via the .htaccess?

Comment: I belive you can use a ["router"](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html) to do this. Unfortunately my internet connection is kinda broken so I can't check that url, but I'm pretty confident it can do the trick for you ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue occurs because Zend by default uses controller/action urls (which is a default route). Because your root controller is `IndexController` and the action is `IndexController::homeAction` it is accessed via `index/home`.

The easiest way to do what you want is adding routes to the `application.ini` as follows:

```
resources.router.routes.home_route_or_any_name.route = "home"
resources.router.routes.home_route_or_any_name.defaults.module = "default"
resources.router.routes.home_route_or_any_name.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.home_route_or_any_name.defaults.action = "home"
```

You can change `home_route_or_any_name` to anything you want. You can also add many routes definitions to fit your needs.

For more information refer to [Zend Framework Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in bootstrap.php

```
/**
 * Setup Routig. 
 * Now all calls are send to indexController like
 * URL/ACTION-1
 * URL/ACTION-2
 *
 * @return void
 **/
protected function _initRouters()
{
    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();

    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        ':action/*',
        array(
            'controller' => 'index',
            'action' => 'index'
        )
    );        

    $router->addRoute('default', $route);
}
```

I will remove index from all the action generated from indexController.
OR
in application.ini

```
routes.index.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
routes.index.route = "/"
routes.index.defaults.module = "default"
routes.index.defaults.controller = "index"
routes.index.defaults.action = "index"
```

For molre detail on routing you can read [here](http://blog.jebrini.net/post/1431025228/url-routing-in-zend-framework-for-dummies)